# Importing configurable products having super product attributes

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, product-attribute, superattribute

I've magento version 1.9.0.1. It's easy to import/export simple product however a little tricky is configurable products. I'm able to import configurable product too but since I don't know what is the heading name and values for the super product attributes I'm unable to get the different select options. I'm attaching the backend of the Super product attributes. If someone can simply write here what heading I must use and how to give it's values in multiple, it would be wonderful.

[image]
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First create one configurable product with associated simple products in the admin panel manually and then export using the export function from *System -> Import/Export-> Export*. You will have the sample .csv file.

There should be some specific columns for configurable products, for instance:

`_super_products_sku`, `_super_attribute_code`, `_super_attribute_option`

Fill in correct data for each configurable product in those columns and import file back using *Import/Export -> Import*

If you want to make price of configurable product change to import superattribute prices you might need to use extension.